# mongoimport в Windows Power Shell

Tags: mongodb, powershell

Чем объяснить ошибку при попытке выполнить команду типа `mongoimport --db ...` через Windows Power Shell? Вот начало текста ошибки:
`mongoimport : Имя "mongoimport" не распознано как имя командлета, функции, файла сценария или выполняемой программы. Проверьте правильность написания имени, а также наличие и правильность пути, после чего повторите попытку.

Comment: Если я всё верно понимаю, то всё дело в PowerShell Execution Policy. Есть совет как обойти Execution Policy лучше всего, чтобы работать с mongodb?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вопрос решился: запускаем PowerShell от имени администратора. Вводим команду `Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted LocalMachine`, разрешающую выполнение скриптов из PowerShell.